# How to convert Complex CSV to JSON?

Tags: python, json, parsing, jsonparser

I have CSV file which contains many fields and strings.

Here is that CSV file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GVLvTqRv80Gfg1fvBYNx0z5xIiiLCHUo/view?usp=sharing

I want the proper JSON format. When I try with normal functions of python I get some fields in below form:

[image]

But I want "population_mesh" and other similar fields in Array (Not String)
-> One more thing is that I also want `"population"`, `"intervention"`, and `"Outcomes"` fields in array form.

Below is the sample target JSON file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y7oGVyOG777APVqOsLBxc9eSd38pDMbc/view?usp=sharing

Actually I tried to convert "population" and other similar fields to array of strings but some string having quotes identified as a part of JSON jormat but escape character has to be put to make exactly like target JSON.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Use of links to off-site resources is also discouraged because they tend to disappear after a while and no one can see them anymore.

Comment: Some columns of your data are `str()` versions of Python lists.  You'll have to apply `ast.literal_eval` to them to convert them back to Python lists.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your coding attempt.  You should also post sample data (reduced to a few rows/columns that illustrate the problem, not your entire data in an external link.